# Toplevel windows widgets are created on parent window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am sorry to ask such a basic question (I'm a beginner in Tkinter). I am working on an application with several windows: a main one, and other modals, using object-oriented programming.

I implement the main class this way :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gWinMain = cMainFrame(tk.Tk())
    gWinMain.mainloop()
```

With cMainFrame :

```
class cMainFrame(tk.Frame):
         
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master, width=WIN_ROOT_WIDTH, height=WIN_ROOT_HEIGHT)
        self.master.title(WIN_ROOT_TITLE)
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        self.master.geometry(str(WIN_ROOT_WIDTH) + 'x' + str(WIN_ROOT_HEIGHT))
        self.grid()
```

In this `__init__`, I create others widgets (menu, labels, canvas, ...). No problem with that.

The menu options should display different modal windows, which are as many classes.
For instance, in `cMainFrame`, I have a method binded on a menu selection :

```
   def emnuFretBoard(self):
        cFretBoardFrame(tk.Toplevel(self))
```

And `cFretBoardFrame` is :

```
class cFretBoardFrame():
         
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        self.master.title(WIN_FRETBOARD_TITLE)
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        self.master.geometry(str(WIN_FRETBOARD_WIDTH) + 'x' + str(WIN_FRETBOARD_HEIGHT))
        self.master.grab_set()
```

This little architecture works, a new modal window displays.
The problem : when I create widgets on this `Toplevel` window, like this on `__init___` of `cFretBoardFrame` :

```
        self.lblTone = tk.Label(text='Tone', padx=20, pady=2)
        self.lblTone.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

... those widgets are created on the main window (on a canvas).

Is there something wrong with this architecture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the master for every widget. If you don't, the master defaults to the root window. In this code you aren't setting the master:

```
self.lblTone = tk.Label(text='Tone', padx=20, pady=2)
```